# Matlab Reading the coordinates from txt file and store them in a matrix

Tags: matlab

I generate 4 multivariate normal samples from given mu and sigma and store them in a txt file. The file consists of the x1-x2 pairs as following.

1 2

3 4

5 6

7 8

So, what I try to do is read them from txt file and store them in 4x2 matrix. Can you give me a solution to accomplish this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dlmread`.

```
A = dlmread('vals.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

Matlab has several functions for this, two of which are [textread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textread.html) and [textscan](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html).